# How to get all the options submitted by form

Tags: python, django, forms

How to get all the options submitted by the form in Django, this is the form which I used.

```
{% extends 'quiz/base.html' %}
{% block content%}
<h1>You are at quiz page</h1>

<form action="{% url 'quiz:process_data' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for question in question_set %}
        <h3>{{question.id}}.{{question.question_text }}</h3>
        {% for option in question.options_set.all %}
            <input type="radio" name="choice{{question.id}}" value="{{ option.options}}" > {{option.options}}<br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock%}
```

I tried `selected_choice=request.POST` ,but getting this as output `csrfmiddlewaretokenchoice1Submitchoice3`. How can I solve this? Thank you

Comment: Request.POST is a dictionary. So just `request.POST.get('form_field_name')`

Comment: Please post your form.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django request.POST is dictionary-like object, see details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST).
So to obtain argument choice in view you can use following syntax:

```
selected_choice=request.POST.get('choice')
```

which return `choice` value or `None` in case this is empty.

Since request.POST is dict-like object you can use `items()` method to get all values and filter them:

```
for k, v in request.POST.items():
    if k.startswith('choice'):
        print(k, v)
```

this will print only those params with `choice` text in name.

Answer (score 0):

```
selected_choice=request.POST.get('choice')
```

The above should work just fine, but if you're crazy, you can try this:

```
{% extends 'quiz/base.html' %}
{% block content%}
<h1>You are at quiz page</h1>

<form action="{% url 'quiz:process_data' %}" method="post" id= "crazyform">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for question in question_set %}
        <h3>{{question.id}}.{{question.question_text }}</h3>
        {% for option in question.options_set.all %}
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="{{ option.options}}" > {{option.options}}<br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="hidden" name="crazychoice" class="crazy" value="nothing">
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock%}
```

Then some JQuery:

```
$('#crazyform input').on('change', function() {
$(".crazy").val($('input[name=choice]:checked', '#crazyform').val())})
```

Everytime you click a radio button, the value of the hidden input field changes to the value of the selected radio button.

Then in your view you can:

```
selected_choice = request.POST.get("crazychoice", "")
```